# How to get data from Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-device-monitor

This is how `Android Device Monitor` look like. But I can not press `Pull file from the device` button. Why?

[image]

Comment: Because you have not selected a file. Your list of files is empty, so you cannot select a file, and hence you cannot pull the selected file. I have heard reports of this sort of problem, where you can no longer browse the directory tree. I have not run experiments to try to reproduce the problem. I usually use `adb pull` from the command line.

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! Tried `adb pull` but find an other problem. Do you have any idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488317/adb-error-remote-object-data-data-com-me-myproject-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get data's from Emulator. You can use Android devices for data's.

Comment: Sure? As I remember earlier somehow I could get data from emulator, but not from device, I haven't rooted device.

Comment: It's weird to see that you get data's from emulator. you dont need to root your device for getting data.