# adb: error: remote object '/data/data/com.me.myproject' does not exist

Tags: android, android-emulator

### 1. Added adb path to ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

### 2. Logged in to emulator

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

### 3. changed permission of the app folder and parent folder

```
chmod 777 /data/data/com.me.myproject
chmod 777 /data/data
```

### 4. Still can not get stuff from outside. Why?

```
adb -s emulator-5554 pull /data/data/com.me.myproject
```

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem and I did this:

1. `adb shell`
2. `run-as com.yourPackageName` (not rooted device)
3. `cp 'database/file_you_want.db' '/sdcard/file_you_want.db'`
4. `exit`
5. `exit` (now you will be back to main terminal window)
6. `adb pull /sdcard/xx.db`

Comment: This only works if the app is in debug mode, not in release

Comment: What should be `xx.db` ?

Comment: @Vencovsk name of our interested file, xx.db is just an example.

Comment: so how to get that for release app?

Comment: @gumuruh Not valid for release build app so far as i know. Maybe try on rooted device.

Answer (score 17):

That's because your debugging Android device is not rooted.

If you have a physical rooted device or have an emulated device, try executing this before, to restart ADB in root mode. Then any command should work:

```
adb root
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the file you wanted to copy needs root permission. It's better to copy the file to /mnt/sdcard/ where you have a right to interact with.

1. `cp <file> /mnt/sdcard/`
2. `adb pull /mnt/sdcard/<file>`

Comment: cp ? where did i type that command? is it inside android studio or inside my mobilephone?

Comment: @gumuruh you need to connect your android to your PC, and use those commands in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. connect mobile to laptop then open adb console
   a). cp  msg-store.db  /mnt/sdcard/    ==>inside /data/data/packagename/databases/
   b). adb pull /mnt/sdcard/msg-store.db/  ===>This will stored in local computer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

prefixing the remote path with ./ or removing the leading / makes the whole difference for me ???  I guess because the system folder must be relative to root's home?

Darn it, those stupid Linux folks wasted my time again.  I admit my whole life is about relative paths but this one got me good.
Make sure you use \ for your target file, stupid Bill G. also decided to go backwards with his slashes and that created a whole mess. :)

PS. What's even weirder both files in my examples were pulled (copied) to the BASH shell current folder NOT c:\
That's stupid or what :)

```
FAILS
adb -s 192.168.1.120:5555 pull /system/media/bootanimation.zip c:\boot1.zip
SUCCEEDS
adb -s 192.168.1.120:5555 pull ./system/media/bootanimation.zip c:\boot1.zip
SUCCEEDS
adb -s 192.168.1.120:5555 pull system/media/bootanimation.zip c:\boot1.zip
```

[image]

[image]